# PHP/PostgreSQL: check if a prepared statement already exists

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I create my prepared statement as:

```
pg_prepare('stm_name', 'SELECT ...');
```

Today, I had a problem (calling twice a function for mistake) when declaring a prepared statement with the same name twice:

```
Warning: pg_prepare() [function.pg-prepare]: Query failed: ERROR: prepared statement "insert_av" already exists in xxx on line 221
```

So, as the question title, there is a way **to check if a prepare statement with the same label already exists, and in case, overwrite it?**

I know this error is from my mistake and will be solved by simply declaring the prepared statements at the begin of my code, but I'm wondering if there is a solution to have more control over them.

**EDIT:**

After the Milen answer, is quite simply to check if the prepared statement is already in use, simply querying the db for the table pg_prepared_statements:

```
try{
    $qrParamExist = pg_query_params("SELECT name FROM pg_prepared_statements WHERE name = $1", array($prepared_statement_name));
    if($qrParamExist){
        if(pg_num_rows($qrParamExist) != 0){
            echo 'parametized statement already created';
        }else{
            echo 'parametized statement not present';
        }
    }else{
        throw new Exception('Unable to query the database.');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But, I don't think this is a good solution, because i have to query the database every time.

Ok, usually the prepared statements are declared in the begin of the script and then just reused, but, I have a class nicely wired and I don't like to declare 10 prepared statements when I'll use just 3 of them.

So, I think I'll use a simple PHP array to keep track the statements I create, and then with `isset()` function check if it exists or needs to be created:

```
try{
    $prepare = pg_prepare('my_stmt_name', "SELECT ...");
    if($prepare){
        $this->rayPrepared['my_stmt_name'] = true;
    }else{
        throw new Exception('Prepared statement failed.');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes necessary use EXECUTE to fix "relation with OID ###### does not exist" error.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get the warning message ? When I don't have this warning message, I spent almost one hour to understand why my code fails. thanks

Comment: @EnsomHodder try with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and with `pg_last_error` when your result from `pg_prepare` or `pg_query` fail (i.e. return false)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way (I hope someone will point out a simpler one):

```
<?
$prepared_statement_name = 'activity1';
$mydbname = '...';

$conn = pg_connect("host=... port=... dbname=... user=... password=...");

$result = pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT name FROM pg_prepared_statements WHERE name = $1', array($prepared_statement_name));

if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $result = pg_prepare($conn, $prepared_statement_name, 'SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname =  $1');
}

$result = pg_execute($conn, $prepared_statement_name, array($mydbname));
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this in php but if this is feasible in your application (if you need the statement only in one place and don't have to "fetch" it again by name) you could try to prepare an unnamed statement.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/libpq-exec.html says:

> PQprepare
> ...
> stmtName may be "" to create an unnamed statement, in which case any pre-existing unnamed statement is automatically replaced; otherwise it is an error if the statement name is already defined in the current session.

php_pg uses PQprepare, so this might work for you.

Comment: Sorry, i have many different prepared statemes.. can used the unnamed.

Comment: Yeah, the "current session". I found out the hard way that "current session" doesn't mean "connection". It's a pity there isn't a robust way to just have the API tell us what we need to know, w/out going and making a query.

Answer (score -5):

Why are you using prepared statements at all ? They only offer a performance advantage if you use the same statement many times over.

Comment: First of all, they offer more security against injection....then, where did i say that i use them just once? ;)

Comment: I tend to agree with this downvote, I only wonder why it downvotes my rep each time you do it, since in fact I was the first guy to do the downvote? Confused.

Comment: Performance benefits are nice, but help against sql injection is nicer.

Comment: To the downvoters: prepared statements do NOT offer more security. Parameterized statements do. And there are separate functions to these. @peufeu mentions a very  valid point. Please just stop persuading people into PS just out of ignorance.

Comment: @Frunsi indeed. Security is achieved by using APIs that make the secure option the easiest and most obvious option.

Comment: @Frunsi -- I know this is old, but my understanding (and I can always be wrong) is prepared statements create an execution plan that wont be deviated from -- so they do mitigate sql injections because sql thats added in place of a string param won't create a new execution flow whereas simple parameterization still allows for arbitrary sql to be passed as string params.

Comment: @Schalton No, postgres provides an interface for parameterized statements that is absolutely safe. The php function is pg_query_params(). It is basically a prepare+execute in a single message, which is faster and causes less database load than doing two separate operations. It also results in better plans, since the actual data is used in the query planning, which is not the case with prepared statements.

Comment: The purpose of prepared statements is to avoid query planning cost when they are used multiple times, at the cost of being slower when used only once. Note that what protects prepared statements against injection is not the fact the execution plan is fixed. It is the fact the parameters are never inserted as strings into the query and instead passed separately as parameters. This also saves the database the work of parsing the parameters out of the query string, so it is both safer and faster.

Comment: Basically you're confusing prepared statements and parameterized queries which are two different things. There is no reason to use prepared statements for safety, that's what pg_query_params() is for.

Comment: I appreciate the nuance in what you're saying, but since prepared statements are parameterized queries this 'debate' seems more like "that's a fast car", "no it's a powerful engine"

It seems that prepared statements do offer security improvements (vs SQL string concatenation) vis-a-vis parameterization while also improving performance through execution plan reuse.

Comment: There is no plan reuse in the typical php web app, so prepared statements are just a way of getting the same safety as you'd get with a parameterized query, but with more database load, code bloat, and chances for bugs. Besides, postgres delays planning until it receives the bind/execute with the parameters, so "prepare" doesn't actually prepare anything or create an execution plan.

Comment: @Schalton -- "... improving performance through execution plan reuse." - Some years and major versions ago (8.x or 9.x or so), executing plans from prepared statements often lead to *inferior performance* - AFAIU because "generic plans" did not consider param values (which can have huge impact on planning). However, in 11 or 12 this got a rewrite and improved a lot. But still - parameterized queries are the better tool for most use cases.

Comment: @Frunsi yeah, postgres devs had to work extra to make it work even for users who don't read the manual and use prepared statements when they should really be using param queries XD (as evidenced by the above comments and DVs)

Comment: @Frunsi -- I won't pretend to know the backstory/development iterations of this feature, but even in Bob's answer he confesses there's performance gains with reuse -- my gut is, if that wasn't the case the feature would be defunct and deprecated.

Interesting note on the "did not consider the param values" -- I usually align my indexing with access patterns so perhaps I'm not paying the penalty of prepared statements planning against one set of values and running against another -- that's something to look out for for sure

Comment: @bobflux You respond so arrogantly without actually reading (or understanding?) what others are saying. Comments like "even for users who don't read the manual and use prepared statements when they should really be using param queries" are why S/O has a bad rap

This question wasn't "Should I use a prepared statement" it was "how to check if a prepared statement exists" answers that make sweeping assumptions about the queries being prepared "There is no plan reuse in the typical php web app" don't add value -- you don't have enough information to make performance recommendations.

Comment: The feature can't be deprecated because it would break apps. Note there are performance benefits for prepared statements in plpgsql functions for example, but you don't have to do anything special, pg will cache plans for plpgsql functions automatically.  This is especially important for triggers, because these can be executed on many rows, so if your trigger has a short SQL query then you really want it to be as fast as possible and to cache the execution plan if the column value statistics allow it, like select on unique/PK index.

Comment: Also if you have a plpgsql function that has quite a bit of code in it, it will be much faster when plans are cached, which gives an extra performance edge to persistent or pooled connections: since the plan cache lives in the session so it is lost if the connection is closed.

Comment: On the client side, there used to be a performance benefit with PREPARE on the ugly and slow antipattern of executing a short query many times in a loop, but postgres proposes a more elegant and much faster solution with VALUES(), WITH and unnest() ; using these, a query can be executed on many values without executing a query in a client-side loop.