# To understand an error message from pg_last_error in PHP

Tags: php, try-catch

Please, see [this answer to see the main problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251967/to-understand-an-error-message-from-pglasterror-in-php/1251974#1251974).

---

**How can you solve the following error message in prepared statement?**

I have a index.php to which I put data through many handlers. The following error message occurs at the following URL that is a URL after a login form.

```
http://localhost/codes/index.php?ask_question&email=masi.masi@gmail.com&passhash_md5=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
```

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193020/php-check-if-an-pgprepare-prepared-statement-already-exist). I get a similar error as Daniel:

```
Warning: pg_prepare() [function.pg-prepare]: Query failed: ERROR: prepared statement "query11" already exists in /var/www/codes/handlers/handle_login_status.php on line 6
Prepared statement failed.
```

in the code *handle_login.php*

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=masi user=masi password=123");
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query11", "SELECT passhash_md5 FROM users
             WHERE email=$1;");
$passhash_md5 = pg_execute($dbconn, "query11", array($_POST['email']));
```

I changed the *handle_login.php* by Daniel's pieces of advice to

```
 $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=masi user=masi password=123");
 try{
     $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query11", "SELECT passhash_md5 FROM users
         WHERE email=$1;");
     if($result){
         $result->rayPrepared['query11'] = true;    // I changed $this to $result
     }else{
         throw new Exception('Prepared statement failed.');
     }
 }catch(Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
 }
 $passhash_md5 = pg_execute($dbconn, "query11", array($_POST['email']));
```

I still get the same error message.

Comment: what's your postgre version? php manual says this only works for 7.4 and above.

Comment: @Zed: PostgreSQL 8.3.7 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.3.real (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3

Comment: I do not know what happened, but after just writing more code and removing old junks the problem vanished. - I will report if it comes back. - Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is  prepare your own implementation? Does it actually throw an exception?

try this

```
if(is_null($result)) {
 throw new Exception("No valid Result");
}
```

**Edit:**
Got the answer in the first comment

```
"Any error in the prepare is available from pg_last_error()."
```

[pg_ last _ error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) (sorry, the underline create the cursiv format)

Comment: If you mean by prepare pg_prepare, then pg_prepare is not my own implementation. It does not seem to throw an exception. I throws me a warning.

Comment: pg_last_error() is useful. It gives me ERROR: prepared statement "query11" already exists. I changed the names of all query11 to query777, but I get the same error for query777.

Comment: Ah, okay, your question title is misleading :)

Comment: I removed $dbconn in $handle_login.php because I have it also at index.php. I get the same error still.

Comment: I renamed the $dbconn to $dbconn2. I changed too all $dbconn to $dbconn2 in *handle_login.php*. I get still the same error.

Comment: check zed's comment on your question. seems to be important.