# does the php pg_connection_busy func discriminate source of busy

Tags: php, database, postgresql, web-development-server

When sending the status request pg_connection_busy(), does the request discriminate between "connection busy" and "server busy" ?

In other words, a server has 100 allowed connections, with one of them applied to the current script.  All 100 connections simultaneously send a query, with 99 of them requiring 2+ seconds of processing time, (theoretically putting the server into a maxed out state thus making it "busy").  One of those 100 requests was a `pg_server_busy()` request.  Would the response be `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_connection_busy()` basically calls libpq's `PQconsumeInput()` followed by `PQisBusy()`, both are documented in 
[Asynchronous Command Processing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html).

This has nothing to do with the server being busy overall with other connections. Also it doesn't send anything to it, query or otherwise, it's purely a local condition about the buffering of the incoming data when retrieving results asynchronously.

Unfortunately the example given by php's documentation is misleading. It calls `pg_connection_busy()` on a new connection without any asynchronous query running, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank for the excellent answer.  Dont suppose you could help me with another one?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/19802833/1658512